# QtCreator and signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

In the QtCreator **change signals/slots** context menu, I can't insert neither signals nor slots that have parameterized arguments such as: QList<QString>, etc. or even references only regular types (int, QSring, etc.)

Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you connect a signal to a socket you use MetaType system of QObject:

connect(sender, SIGNAL(updated(QList<MyClass>), receiver, SLOT(list_updated(QList<MyClass>))

The parameter of the signal and slot is of "QList<MyClass>" metatype. Since it is custom metatype, Qt library has no knowledge of underlying implementation type.

> Declare new types with
>   Q_DECLARE_METATYPE() to make them
>   available to QVariant and other
>   template-based functions. Call
>   qRegisterMetaType() to make type
>   available to non-template based
>   functions, such as the queued signal
>   and slot connections.

So you need to add metatype declaration before you make connection:

```
qRegisterMetaType<MyClass>("MyClass");
qRegisterMetaType<QList<MyClass> >("QList<MyClass>");
```

Comment: Ouch, didn't know Qt could get so ugly `:(`

Comment: IMHO it's not ugly, but instead wonderful!
Because in this way you can export a custom class in a QVariant, and you can do whatever you want!
Such as serialization or maybe something like CORBA with signal and slots...
Think the possibility!